A blackboard bold `\varepsilon`
I want to have a blackboard bold version of the usual \varepsilon. When using \usepackage[bbgreekl]{mathbbol} and \bbespilon, the result has two issues:

It looks like \epsilon, not like \varepsilon

It is pixelated


How can I achieve a blackboard bold version of \varepsilon without these issues?

MWE:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[bbgreekl]{mathbbol}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathbb}{AMSb}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathbx}{bbold}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{ccc}
\epsilon & \varepsilon & \bbespilon \\
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}



You can use the bboldx package to get the non-pixelated lowercase epsilon, but I am not aware of a package with provides CM matching lowercase mathbb letters. NewCM has lowercase pi, gamma and uppercase sigma, pi and gamma though.

@ApoorvPotnis Can you give a MWE? I can't get bboldx to work for some reason.

I just tried to compile a document using bboldx, can unfortunately I cannot get it to work as well. However, I could get the doublestruck epsilon using {\usefont{U}{bboldx}{m}{n}\char'017}. I don't know what's going wrong.

Wait, I just tried your MWE in the question, and I get a non-pixelated mathbb epsilon!

@ApoorvPotnis I can't get {\usefont{U}{bboldx}{m}{n}\char'017} to work either. Can you provide a MWE?

@ApoorvPotnis Here is a 7z file containing my TeX file, the resulting PDF and PNG : https://files.catbox.moe/p14djm.7z

@ApoorvPotnis Here are the individual files contained in that 7z file

@ApoorvPotnis The TeX file : https://files.catbox.moe/lh67k6.tex

@ApoorvPotnis The log file : https://files.catbox.moe/vycjzy.log

@ApoorvPotnis The PDF file : https://files.catbox.moe/cp68wl.pdf

@ApoorvPotnis The PNG file : https://files.catbox.moe/cpeizs.PNG

@ApoorvPotnis I finally understood what you meant by {\usefont{U}{bboldx}{m}{n}\char'017}: To use it in text mode, not in math mode. Does anybody have an idea how to render that character in math mode and not in text mode?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

If you must, you can overstrike the normal varepsilon

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[bbgreekl]{mathbbol}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathbb}{AMSb}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathbx}{bbold}
\newcommand\bbvarepsilon{\varepsilon\mkern-12.3mu\shortmid}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{ccc}
\epsilon & \varepsilon & \bbvarepsilon  \\
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}


Thanks for the answer. However, I would really like to use a proper font instead of making the character myself, so I'm not going to accept this answer.

@Smiley1000 I know of a lot of fonts but I don't know of any that has this so using  a font  glyph may involve editing a font in fontforge or similar to design and add such a glyph, which would be better but harder to be portable and font design isn't clearly on topic here. However perfectly reasonable not to accept and see if someone does know of a suitable font

Looking here https://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/mtp2lite/texmf/tex/latex/mtpro2/mtpro2.sty, I think that the nice solution is in mtpro2 using mtpbbi option on pag. 9:

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[mtpbbi]{mtpro2}
\begin{document}
$\mathbb{\varepsilon}$
\end{document}



