How to fix the following error: " ! Illegal parameter number in definition of \mytmp. "?
I would like to create a table that looks like this:
Version 1:
\[
\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & \char0 \\
1 & \char1 \\
...
254 & \char254 \\
255 & \char255 \\
\end{array}
\]

Version 2:
\[
\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & \char0 & {\usefont{U}{bboldx}{m}{n}\char0} \\
1 & \char1 & {\usefont{U}{bboldx}{m}{n}\char1} \\
...
254 & \char254 & {\usefont{U}{bboldx}{m}{n}\char254} \\
255 & \char255 & {\usefont{U}{bboldx}{m}{n}\char255} \\
\end{array}
\]

The code is based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/165153/271855 .

Here is my successful code for version 1:
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgffor, etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newtoks\@tabtoks
\newcommand\addtabtoks[1]{\global\@tabtoks\expandafter{\the\@tabtoks#1}}
\newcommand\eaddtabtoks[1]{\edef\mytmp{#1}\expandafter\addtabtoks\expandafter{\mytmp}}
\newcommand*\resettabtoks{\global\@tabtoks{}}
\newcommand*\printtabtoks{\the\@tabtoks}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{80pt}
\resettabtoks
\foreach \x in {0,...,255} {
  \eaddtabtoks{\x & \char\x}
  \addtabtoks{\\}
}
\[
\begin{array}{cc}
\printtabtoks
\end{array}
\]
\end{minipage}

\end{document}

Here is the output:
Output

Here is my unsuccessful code for version 2:
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgffor, etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newtoks\@tabtoks
\newcommand\addtabtoks[1]{\global\@tabtoks\expandafter{\the\@tabtoks#1}}
\newcommand\eaddtabtoks[1]{\edef\mytmp{#1}\expandafter\addtabtoks\expandafter{\mytmp}}
\newcommand*\resettabtoks{\global\@tabtoks{}}
\newcommand*\printtabtoks{\the\@tabtoks}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{100pt}
\resettabtoks
\foreach \x in {0,...,255} {
  \eaddtabtoks{\x & \char\x & {\usefont{U}{bboldx}{m}{n}\char\x}}
  \addtabtoks{\\}
}
\[
\begin{array}{ccc}
\printtabtoks
\end{array}
\]
\end{minipage}

\end{document}

Here is the log:
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (MiKTeX 24.4) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2024.7.21)  21 JUL 2024 22:22
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**"C:/Users/eliai/Sync/[Müll]/varepsilon test 3/test.tex"
(C:/Users/eliai/Sync/[Müll]/varepsilon test 3/test.tex
LaTeX2e <2024-06-01> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2024-05-27>
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/standalone\standalone.cls
Document Class: standalone 2022/10/10 v1.3b Class to compile TeX sub-files stan
dalone
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tools\shellesc.sty
Package: shellesc 2023/07/08 v1.0d unified shell escape interface for LaTeX
Package shellesc Info: Restricted shell escape enabled on input line 77.
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2019/10/25 v1.5 ifluatex legacy package. Use iftex instead.

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/xkeyval\xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2022/06/16 v2.9 package option processing (HA)

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkeyval.tex
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks17
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks18

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\keyval.tex))
\XKV@depth=\count194
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
\sa@internal=\count195
\c@sapage=\count196

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/standalone\standalone.cfg
File: standalone.cfg 2022/10/10 v1.3b Default configuration file for 'standalon
e' class
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2024/02/08 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2024/02/08 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count197
\c@section=\count198
\c@subsection=\count199
\c@subsubsection=\count266
\c@paragraph=\count267
\c@subparagraph=\count268
\c@figure=\count269
\c@table=\count270
\abovecaptionskip=\skip49
\belowcaptionskip=\skip50
\bibindent=\dimen141
)
\sa@box=\box52
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/utilities\pgffor.sty
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/utilities\pgfrcs.sty
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil-common.tex
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks19
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen142
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen143
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil-latex.def
\pgfutil@abb=\box53
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfrcs.code.tex
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf\pgf.revision.tex)
Package: pgfrcs 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys.sty
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks20
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks21

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeyslibraryfiltered.code.
tex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks22
))) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/math\pgfmath.sty
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath.code.tex
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathutil.code.tex
\pgf@x=\dimen144
\pgf@xa=\dimen145
\pgf@xb=\dimen146
\pgf@xc=\dimen147
\pgf@y=\dimen148
\pgf@ya=\dimen149
\pgf@yb=\dimen150
\pgf@yc=\dimen151
\c@pgf@counta=\count271
\c@pgf@countb=\count272
\c@pgf@countc=\count273
\c@pgf@countd=\count274
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathparser.code.tex
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen152
\pgfmath@count=\count275
\pgfmath@box=\box54
\pgfmath@toks=\toks23
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks24
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks25
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.code.tex)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.co
de.tex)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex)

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code.
tex)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmeti
cs.code.tex) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathcalc.code.tex
) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfloat.code.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count276
)))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgffor.code.tex
Package: pgffor 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgffor@iter=\dimen153
\pgffor@skip=\dimen154
\pgffor@stack=\toks26
\pgffor@toks=\toks27
))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/etoolbox\etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count277
)
\@tabtoks=\toks28

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2024-05-08 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count278
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box55
) (test.aux)
\openout1 = `test.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 13.

! Illegal parameter number in definition of \mytmp.
<to be read again> 
                   1
l.20 }
      
? 
! Emergency stop.
<to be read again> 
                   1
l.20 }
      
End of file on the terminal!

 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 6533 strings out of 473903
 130743 string characters out of 5736394
 1925908 words of memory out of 5000000
 29372 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 558069 words of font info for 36 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 57i,1n,71p,406b,108s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

How can I fix this error?

there are lots of existing packages for typesetting font tables

the posted code runs without error  but multiple Missing character: There is no � in font cmr10! warnings. so does not match your question

you would get the error from \newcommand\eaddtabtoks[1]{\edef\mytmp{##1}\expandafter\addtabtoks\expandafter{\mytmp}} with ##1 and the fix would be to use the code you posted in the question

@DavidCarlisle I don't really understand how this can be happening - I've posted precisely the code and output from my machine. Are there any other factors that might influence this?

@DavidCarlisle Turns out I was missing a \noexpand

Turns out I was missing a \noexpand before the \usefont:
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgffor, etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newtoks\@tabtoks
\newcommand\addtabtoks[1]{\global\@tabtoks\expandafter{\the\@tabtoks#1}}
\newcommand\eaddtabtoks[1]{\edef\mytmp{#1}\expandafter\addtabtoks\expandafter{\mytmp}}
\newcommand*\resettabtoks{\global\@tabtoks{}}
\newcommand*\printtabtoks{\the\@tabtoks}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{100pt}
\resettabtoks
\foreach \x in {0,...,255} {
  \eaddtabtoks{\x & char\x & {\noexpand\usefont{U}{bboldx}{m}{n}\char\x}}
  \addtabtoks{\\}
}
\[
\begin{array}{ccc}
\printtabtoks
\end{array}
\]
\end{minipage}

\end{document}


No need of \foreach, \expandafter and \noexpand.
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\maketable}{mmmm}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__smiley_font_tl { \usefont{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4} }
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
  \int_step_function:nnN {0} {255} \__smiley_printrow:n
  \end{tabular}
 }

\tl_new:N \l__smiley_font_tl
\cs_new:Npn \__smiley_printrow:n #1 { #1 & \l__smiley_font_tl \symbol{#1} \\ }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\maketable{U}{bboldx}{m}{n}

\end{document}



Thanks for your answer. This seems really good. Also, it seems like it could be an answer to this other question of mine : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/722927/a-blackboard-bold-varepsilon . Would you mind to take a look at it?
